# Adjust elements inside a table cell <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with elements that goes outside a modal:

[image]

```
<table class="table" style="margin-bottom:15px;border: 1px solid #DDD;">
    <tbody><tr><td class="text-left" style="color: #FFF;background: #73879C;"><b>textextext:</b></td><td rowspan="4" style="border-left: 1px solid #DDD;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image1...jpeg</button></a><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image2...jpeg</button></a><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image3...jpeg</button></a><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image4...jpeg</button></a></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="text-left">textextext</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="text-left" style="color: #FFF;background: #73879C;"><b>textextext:</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="text-left">textextext</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I tried to use **word-wrap** but it's still the same, and I want to adjust these elements inside that table cell.

**MODAL CODE:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">textextex</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body"><table class="table tblTrad_Rev" style="margin-bottom:15px;border: 1px solid #DDD;"><tbody>
<tr><td class="text-left" style="color: #FFF;background: #73879C;"><b>textet:</b></td><td rowspan="4" style="border-left: 1px solid #DDD;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image1...JPG</button></a> <a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image2...JPG</button></a> <a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image3...JPG</button></a> <a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>image4...JPG</button></a></td></tr>
<tr><td class="text-left">Ltextextex</td></tr>
<tr><td class="text-left" style="color: #FFF;background: #73879C;"> 
<b>textet:</b></td></tr>
<tr><td class="text-left">textextex</td></tr></tbody>
</table></div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
```

How can I fix it ?

I'd like your help.

Comment: if you put that code in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4Lzhnmuy/4/ inside a wrapping div you will see it does what you want, so your code above is not enough to troubleshoot as the issue lies in your modal wrapper styles/markup, and how this table code is inside it.  maybe that will help you get on the right track.

Comment: try with overflow:hidden

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap you can handle this behavior.

P.S: I added more entry in the right cell to show you example.

Please see

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Display modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table" style="margin-bottom:15px;border: 1px solid #DDD;">
    <tbody><tr><td class="text-left" style="color: #FFF;background: #73879C;"><b>textextext:</b></td><td rowspan="4" style="border-left: 1px solid #DDD;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image1...jpeg</button></a><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image2...jpeg</button></a><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image1...jpeg</button></a><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image2...jpeg</button></a><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image1...jpeg</button></a><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image2...jpeg</button></a><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image1...jpeg</button></a><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image2...jpeg</button></a><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image3...jpeg</button></a><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/EcTpuSWRqaePaBBdvK3A"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> image4...jpeg</button></a></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="text-left">textextext</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="text-left" style="color: #FFF;background: #73879C;"><b>textextext:</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="text-left">textextext</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap but it's still the same

Comment: can you show me your code so I can investigate please ?

Comment: I saw that, and I build my code from your code. You can see that if you run the snippet I made above.  I want to see your code structure so I can help you debug your code.

Comment: @NekoLopez, no response.. Did my post helped you?